# Assigning container iterators with pre/post-incrementers

Tags: c++

I was assigning a vector iterator to the element after a different vector iterator and encountered some strange behavior.

```cpp
//This ended up assigning it2 equal to it1
std::vector<int>::iterator it2 = ++it1;
//This worked, assigning it2 to the element after it1
std::vector<int>::iterator it2 = it1++;
```

I was wondering why these two calls behaved differently? I would have thought they would be functionally the same, with the first one being slightly more efficient.

Comment: Your comment for the second case is incorrect. That code results in it2 pointing to the element **before** it1.

Answer (score 1):

Both expressions `++it1` and `it1++` increment `it1` but they have different values. It's the value that gets assigned to `it2`.

The value of `++it1` is the value of `it1` after it has been incremented.

The value of `it1++` is the value of `it1` before it has been incremented.

Comment: ah yes, it's been a while since I used c++, thanks for that reminder